# C# try and catch inside a do while

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch, do-while

I am a beginner in C# and programming in general. I have coded a program that is required to have a method, do-while, if-else and try-catch. I have coded the program perfectly and it works as well, but as soon as i added the try-catch loop, a **fahr** variable outside the try block started showing an "Use of unassigned local variable" error (celsius = FahrToCel(**fahr**). I am attaching the code, please can someone tell me whats wrong with it.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bastun
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double FahrToCel(int fahr)
        {
            double celsius = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9; //convert fahrenheit to celsius
            return celsius;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            int fahr; //declaring variable for temperature in fahrenheit
            double celsius = 0; //declaring variable for temperature in celsius
            do //start loop
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the current temperature of the sauna?"); //show message on screen

                try
                {
                    fahr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //read the value of Fahrenheit and convert to int
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input format. Please try again and input a number."); //error message to be shown in case wrong value is entered
                continue;
}

                celsius = FahrToCel(fahr); //calling the method

                if (celsius < 73) //show message if entered temperature is less than 73 celsius
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sauna is cold. Raise temperature.");
                }
                else if (celsius > 77) //show message if entered temperature is more than 77 celsius
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sauna is too hot. Lower temperature.");
                }
                else if (celsius > 73 && celsius < 77) //show message if entered temperature is in between 73 and 77 celsius
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sauna is perfectly warm. Enjoy!");
                }
                else if (celsius == 75) //show message if entered temperature is equal to 75 celsius
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Optimal temperature achieved. Enjoy!");
                }
            }
            while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77); //continue loop if temperature is less than 73 or more than 77 celsius
            Console.ReadKey();
            

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: That problem is solved now as i have made some changes to the coding, but another problem has crept up. The program now is not showing any message when the user enters 164 or 165 fahrenheit (73, 74 celsius). Moreover, its not showing the message it should when the temperature is at 75 celsius, instead its showing the message for 73-77 celsius.

Comment: Initialize fahr with a value when declaring it e.g. 0 -> int fahr = 0;

Comment: That creates another problem. If the user enters an invalid format into the program, it shows the programmed catch error message, like it should, but it also shows the message that it needs to show if the entered temperature is too low. I think that is because i have pre-declared the fahr to be 0 which is a low value.

Comment: There is two conditional <= and >= that you are not considering on the last print, you can even avoid the last else if, and only set it to ELSE, thats when not any of the others IFs Elses fall.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *do* block is not exited in case something goes wrong in the *try* block. In this case all the remaining code is executed with an unassigned *fahr* variable.

To abort the current iteration and continue with the loop use *continue* instuction in the catch block, like

```
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input format. Please try again and input a number."); 
    continue;
}
```

Comment: That did it! But i still declared the value of celsius to 0. The program is working fine now as far as i can tell. Thanks!